# Do you have to hit for effects to occur or do they occur whether you hit or miss?

Tags: dnd-4e

An example of what I am trying to understand is the power Brash Assault.  The effect states "Effect: The target can make a melee basic attack against you as a free action and has combat advantage for the attack. If the target makes this attack, an ally of your choice within 5 squares of the target can make a basic attack against the target as a free action and has combat advantage for the attack.
"

My GM says that I need to hit with the attack to offer the effect and gain the ally attacks.  I think he is wrong and the effect happens whether I hit or miss.  Please advise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is easily resolved: there's a whole section in the PHB that tells you how to read power descriptions.  Turn to p.59, and look at the part on what "Effects" means.  It says that

> Many powers produce effects that take place regardless of whether your attack roll succeeds, and other powers have effects that occur without an attack roll being required.

So there you go; the effect happens regardless of whether you hit or not.  That's the whole point of *having* separate Hit, Miss, and Effect lines.

I'd assume there's a similar description in their digital content, but to be honest I haven't followed 4e since its release.

Answer (score 6):

The keyword "Effect" means that it happens *when you use the power*, regardless of whether you hit or miss.

The keyword "Hit" means that it only happens *on a hit*.

For example, my monk's power "One Hundred Leaves" has the following stat block:

> **Attack:** Dexterity vs. Reflex
>
> **Hit:** 3d8 + Dexterity modifier damage, and you push the target 2 squares.
>
> **Miss:** Half damage, and you push the target one square.
>
> **Effect:** Until the end of your next turn, you can target one additional creature in range with your flurry of blows power.

This means that when I use the power, I get the additional flurry of blows attack *regardless of* whether I hit or not. Then, if I hit, I get what's under the "hit" block, and if I miss, I get what's under the "miss" block. It's the same in your case - effects happen regardless of a hit.

ETA: Whoops, someone else answered while I was typing. Still, hopefully this helps clarify.

Answer (score -4):

If a Power has a section which specifies:
Attack: X vs. Y

(X being one of the abilities, and Y being one of the Defensive Stats.)

That means you perform a roll to determine the 'Success' of the Power in Question.
It does not have to be such a literal term as 'Hit' or 'Miss'.

With 'Brash Assault' the factor determined can be viewed as the Coordination between you and the Ally - Do you succeed in coordinating? Hit or Miss.

In simple Terms, Yes. It (you) need to 'Hit' / 'Succeed' on a Roll in order to work.

Comment: In Brash Assault. The card reads: Attack: Strength vs. AC
Hit: 1[W] + Strength modifier damage. The X vs Y affects the hit and damage. The effect is them below that.

Comment: I see. I would seem I was wrong.